# How to take user input in maps and multipmaps?

Tags: c++, stl, maps, containers

I just studied multimaps (working and other related stuff). 
Here, I found this code snippet

```
gquiz1.insert(pair <int, int> (5, 40)); 
gquiz1.insert(pair <int, int> (4, 30)); 
gquiz1.insert(pair <int, int> (3, 60)); 
gquiz1.insert(pair <int, int> (1, 20)); 
gquiz1.insert(pair <int, int> (5, 50)); 
gquiz1.insert(pair <int, int> (6, 50)); 
gquiz1.insert(pair <int, int> (6, 10));
```

but was wondering, what if the user wants to enter the value of key and data at the run time in spite of giving statically. I am new to STL. please, help that how could I take the values of the above code at the run time in spite of giving statically?

Comment: Are you asking how to receive user input in general?

Comment: Note: a more modern way to perform static initialization would be something like `std::multimap<int, int> gquiz1 = { {5,40}, {4,30}, {3,60} } ;`

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is possible:

```
int main()
{
    std::multimap<int, int> gquiz1;
    int key, val;
    std::cin >> key >> val;
    gquiz1.insert(std::pair<int, int>(key, val));

    //print map content
    for(const auto& elem: gquiz1)
    {
        std::cout << elem.first << " " << elem.second << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Try it online](https://onlinegdb.com/B1HC1SVSI)

---

`std::multimap` (or any other container) doesn't care where input is from. It's up to you, the Programmer, to know where the data should come from, to pass it to a container to to use it later. Literal is one option, if you need a constant that never changes. You can also calculate something, read input from user, from file, from database, from Internet or anywhere your program has access to.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the only what you need to do is to substitute integer literals

```
gquiz1.insert(pair <int, int> (5, 40));
```

for variables

```
gquiz1.insert(pair <int, int> (key, value));
```

because variables can be assigned at run-time with any values for example from a user input.

Here is a demonstrative program that uses two methods `emplace` and `insert`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() 
{
    std::multimap<int, int> m;

    int key, value;

    key = 5; value = 40;

    m.emplace( key, value );

    key = 4; value = 30;

    m.insert( { key, value } );

    for ( const auto &item : m )
    {
        std::cout << "{ " << item.first << ", " << item.second << " } ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
{ 4, 30 } { 5, 40 }
```